# open application1 within application2?

Tags: import, unity-game-engine, porting, maya, texture-mapping

pretty novice programmer here so this question is more theoretical than anything. How would one go about opening an application, say Maya, within another application, say second life? I'm thinking about how two users could collaborate and model something in Maya while within a virtual environment. Is there a way to port Maya's interface to a surface in Unity using a texture map or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) to perform  the tasks you are talking about.